# Additional drivers for NVIDIA graphics card cannot be installed

Tags: nvidia, hybrid-graphics

My laptop runs on Ubuntu 13.10 and has NVIDIA GT 520MX discrete graphics. But Additional Drivers in Software & Updates shows that 'No additional drivers are available'. Why is it so? How can I install the correct driver?

Answer (score 0):

1. Download the Nvidia driver if 32bit [here](http://www.nvidia.com/object/linux-display-ia32-285.05.09-driver) else if 64bit [here](http://www.nvidia.com/object/linux-display-amd64-285.05.09-driver)
2. Install the driver manually [This link will help you](http://www.nvidia.com/object/linux-display-ia32-304.108-driver)
3. To install it manually

First press ctrl + alt +f1 This will open tty1

Now you are using the tty terminal console

log in with your user name and password

Now stop the lightdm(dgm or whatever) using the command

```
sudo stop lightdm
```

Then install the new driver with

```
sudo sh /path-to-the-driver
```

- if something goes wrong close the installer and reboot then try again
- still same problem the nvidia installer will make a black list in /etc/modprobe.d/
- if this is not generated you have to make such file to black list nouveau
- Run sudoedit /etc/modprobe.d/nvidia-graphics-drivers.conf and fill it with this:
  blacklist nouveau
- If the problem is not solve you have to add the string "nomodeset" to your /etc/default/grub, in GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT= line
- then update the grub

  sudo update-grub

Comment: But my discrete graphics has OPTIMUS technology. I could find out that OPTIMUS is not officially supported in Linux. What should I do in this context?

Comment: @sid just make the steps above